# why i keep seeing this text "mhchem-textmhchem-math"

Tags: errors

everytime i compile i see the text at the top of the cover. I searched all the document looking for this text without luck.

[image]

any help?

```
\input{doc_config/doc_config} % Document Configurations

\input{sections/0_doc_info} % Document information

\input{doc_config/headers_and_footers} % Headers and footers

\input{doc_config/defined_stuff} % User defined environments


\begin{document}

\sffamily

\pagenumbering{alph}

\input{./doc_config/cover} % COVER
\newpage\thispagestyle{EmptyPage}
\mbox{}\newpage

\pagenumbering{roman}

% TABLE OF CONTENTS
\tableofcontents

%\mbox{}\newpage
\listoftables

%\mbox{}\newpage
\listoffigures

% DOCUMENT SECTIONS
\newpage\input{./sections/1_intro/1_intro}
\newpage\input{./sections/2_sizing/2_sizing}
\newpage\input{./sections/3_materials/3_materials}
\newpage\input{./sections/4_wing/4_wing}
\newpage\input{./sections/5_tail/5_tail}
\newpage\input{./sections/6_fuselage/6_fuselage}
\newpage\input{./sections/7_landingGear/7_landingGear}
\newpage\input{./sections/8_designPoint/8_designPoint}
\newpage\input{./sections/9_engineAssembly/9_engineAssembly}
\newpage\input{./sections/10_CG/10_CG}
%%

\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

im using texworks, and when i control click over the text "mhchem-textmhchem-math" it tells me that i have written this on \begin {document}

Comment: You should show us the code you used ...  Welcome!

Comment: yes, but its a large document. I have a main that calls other documents, and another part that i use to make the cover, header, etc. that is also called by the main document

Comment: You cannot except that we will help you because our PDF outputs typically don't include mhchem-textmhchem-math. What you can try to do is to create *minimal example*. I. e. try to select only such minimal part of your large document where the problem occurs. You must to do this by several iteration steps. And if you try this then you probably find the problem yourself! So, you will not need to help at this site.

Comment: As others have commented, there's no way for any of us to guess the problem from the code fragment you've given us. I suggest you either [build up](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/buildingup.html) or [hack down](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/hackingdown.html) to create a test document that reproduces the problem. If the problem occurs at the start of the document, then the building up method is probably the best approach. Start with a test that just has the document class and `\begin{document}\end{document}` and then start adding bits to the preamble.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Your problem is hidden in one of yours "input" files. In which one, you need to discover yourself, since their contents is unknown to us.

Answer (score 5):

The strings `mhchem-text` and `mhchem-math` both appear in `mhchem.sty`

```
3017: { \chemgreek_get_from_mapping:nn { mhchem-math } {#1} }
3018: { \chemgreek_get_from_mapping:nn { mhchem-text } {#1} }
3195:   \chemgreek_declare_mapping_alias:nn { mhchem-text } {#1}
3200:   \chemgreek_declare_mapping_alias:nn { mhchem-math } {#1}
3299:   \chemgreek_declare_mapping_alias:nn { mhchem-text } { \l_chemgreek_active_mapping_tl }
3303:   \chemgreek_declare_mapping_alias:nn { mhchem-math } { \l_chemgreek_active_mapping_tl }
```

so one of those commands is not acting as intended and the argument is just "falling through" and being typeset.

The most likely cause is that you have updated `mhchem` and not updated the `expl3` package on which it depends, or updated `expl3` and not updated `mhchem`.

It seems *highly* unlikely that you got that output without an error. Note that when TeX recovers from errors the recovery is designed to let it carry on to check for more errors it does not try to make sensible output, so after an error you should look at the *log* and not the pdf output (and similarly the log would be more useful than the output to post to the question as it would show the exact error, and your package versions.

The following document produces this output matching your description

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% fake mismatched packages
\usepackage{mhchem}
\expandafter\let\csname chemgreek_declare_mapping_alias:nn\endcsname\undefined

\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

But more useful than the pdf, the above produces an error log:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \chemgreek_declare_mapping_alias:nn 
                                               {mhchem-text}{\l_chemgreek_ac...
l.7 \begin{document}

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \chemgreek_declare_mapping_alias:nn 
                                               {mhchem-math}{\l_chemgreek_ac...
l.7 \begin{document}

?
```